# md-select disappear on select the second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here are screenshots in order of operation:

> 1. option is well shown and clicked

[image: 1]

> 2. values went through

[image: 2]

> 3. same option is about to be clicked.

[image: 3]

> 4. **problem is here**, option is now disappeared.

[image: 4]

> 5. however when the option is added,

[image: 5]

> It still goes through well even though the value is not shown.

[image: 6]

I have md-select which acts with an add button

```
<md-card-content >
<div layout="row" class="md-padding" ng-cloak>
    <md-input-container style="margin-right: 10px;">
        <label>CMD</label>
        <md-select style="min-width: 200px;" ng-model="selectedCmd" >
            <md-option ng-repeat="(x, y) in cmds" ng-value="y">
                {{y.cmd}}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container ng-repeat="(key, value) in selectedCmd" ng-if="$index > 0">
        <label >{{key}}</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="selectedCmd[key]">
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container>
        <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="addRow(selectedCmd)" ng-if="selectedCmd"> ADD </md-button>
    </md-input-container>

</div>
</md-card-content>
```

and in script I have this function that acts as the add button is clicked.

```
$scope.rows = [];
var temp = {};

$scope.addRow = function(selectedCmd) {
    $scope.temp = angular.copy(selectedCmd);
    $scope.temp.cmd = $scope.temp.cmd.match(/\d+/)[0]; //only gets the number infront
    $scope.rows.push($scope.temp);

    for (var key in selectedCmd) {
        if (key !== 'cmd') {
            selectedCmd[key] = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I found out that after the execution of `for loop` above, the selected option is not visible when it is selected after the first time. The option is still there to click but only the label is shown twice when it is clicked. How would I prevent this?

EDIT: This works. so chekcing `keyName !== 'cmd'` is causing the problem but I do not know how and why.

```
for ( var keyName in selectedCmd) {
    if (keyName === 'Imageurl'
        || keyName === 'Threshold'
    ) {
        selectedCmd[keyName] = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that for loop is the culprit. You are clearing value of selectedCmd if key!=='cmd'. This condition is getting true. you need to checkout by debugging why that condition is getting true.

Comment: @KaranDesai It is not getting true. If it were, the option in the third image will also be blank  and the second value should not have 'cmd' : '1'.